# basic question about open balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be an open set in a complete normed space. Let $x \in U$. Hence, we can find an open ball $B$ centered at $x$ that lies inside $U$.

Question: Does it follow that $U - x $ contains an open ball centered at $0$ ?

Comment: We don't even know that $0\in U$, so it's hardly the case that we know any open ball centered on $0$ is in $U$.

Comment: Instead of $U \setminus \{x\}$, do you mean the translation of $U$, $U - x$?

Comment: you are right goos! sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U$, then $B(0, \epsilon) \subset U - x$.  Fix $z \in B(0, \epsilon)$.
Then $\|z + x - x \| < \epsilon$.
Therefore $z + x \in B(x, \epsilon)$.
Therefore $z + x \in U$.  Therefore $z \in U - x$.

Answer (score 0):

$U\backslash\{x\}$ is still an open set, and contains an open ball centered in every point of $U$ but $x$.

No reason to assume $0$ has some role here. Example: $\mathbb{C}, U=B_1{(2i)}$

Maybe you mean $\tau_{-x}(U)$, where $\tau_{-x}$ is the translation of $U$ such that $\tau_{-x}(x) = 0$ and it is an isometry. In that case, yes.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your notation.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, we have an open ball $B \subset U$ centered at $x$. It easily follows that the translation $U - x$ contains the translated ball $B - x$, which is clearly a ball of the same radius centered at $0$.

The above argument can be used more generally to show that if $U$ is open, so is any translation $U + y$.